# Inverse Regular Expressions Match in Webpack SVGO-Loader

Tags: regex, webpack

I have a regular expression looking for `.svg` files under the `icons-wc/icons` directory for a Webpack `svgo-loader`.

```regex
/icons-wc\\icons\\.*\.svg$/
```

I'd now like to find all `.svg` files outside the `icons-wc/icons` directory but I'm not sure how to approach it. I've tried something like this but that doesn't seem to work. It seems to be too over eager to select

```regex
/(?<!icons-wc\\icons)\\.*\.svg$/
```

Comment: You might do it the other way around using a negative lookahead `^(?!.*icons-wc\\icons)\\.*\.svg$`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
/^(?!.*(?:^|[\\\/])icons-wc[\\\/]icons[\\\/]).*\.svg$/
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/fDY8be/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [\\\/]                   any character of: '\\', '\/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    icons-wc                 'icons-wc'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\\\/]                   any character of: '\\', '\/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    icons                    'icons'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\\\/]                   any character of: '\\', '\/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  svg                      'svg'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```